# request.user in generic view and in pure function in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I was using django-rest-framework-simplejwt for authentication. Here is my settings.py file[settings.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trDzF.png)

Initially I was trying to get login user by accessing request.user in a view function as shown below and passing access token in headers berear token:
[function test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKC8g.png)

But I wasn't able to get the logged in user. Instead when I tried RetreiveAPIView of rest framework generics, it gave me the user..Here is the code for the same..[Using RetreiveAPIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMoA.png)
[UserSerializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH3bc.png)
Initially I thought that both the request objects are same but it seems that there is some difference.. Can anyone explain me what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

please show your whole View, not only a test method.
In DRF views you can access a request and request.user as a method parameter which is automatically passed into methods of View Class, not a class property (self.request)
look at drf docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/